# Not able add extra IP to vps server in OVH

Tags: centos, ip, vps

I am trying to add extra IP to my OVH vps server by following there guide but getting this error.
I am using cent os 6 - 64bit using this guide to add IP to my vps server 
https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/dedicated/network-ipaliasing/

```
"# ifup eth0:0
ipcalc: bad netmask: 255.255.255.255
ipcalc: bad netmask: 255.255.255.255
 is already in use for device eth0...79
/".or: an inet prefix is expected rather than "54.xx.xx.xxx
.for eth0:0g address 54.xx.xx.xxx
bind: Cannot assign requested address"
```

Where  am I wrong? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Is it a dedicated server or VPS? Ask the OVH support if they allow additional IP on a VPS

Try using Prefix instead of NETMASK